# error while doing insert data from a file to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

there is a file containing data that I want to insert into table in mysql using python.I retrieved the data from file using "with open" and converted it to a list.so now in the list the elements are string and i want to change string to tuple so that i can retrieve the data from this to mysql.

```
    import mysql.connector


    with open("/home/ninky/com.csv", "r") as fp:
        content = fp.read()
    lines = content.split("\n")
    print(lines)

        myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", database="EMPSALARY" 
        cur = myconn.cursor()
        db = "insert into PERSON(name,age,year)values(%s,%s,%s)"
        myconn = cur.execute(db, lines)
        myconn.close()
```

```
result:
-----------
['deepak,29,2019', 'ninky,29,2010', 'suraj,29,2020', 'pratap,30,2018', '']
deepak,29,2019
ninky,29,2010
suraj,29,2020
pratap,30,2018
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ninky/PycharmProjects/new/csv_db.py", line 23, in <module>
>     cur.execute(db, lines)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
> line 543, in execute
>     "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement") mysql.connector.errors. ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used
> in the SQL statement
> ```

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lines what you have is a list containing each line of your CSV file. Then, you need to iterate through all lines and do a split again on your separator (','):

```
import mysql.connector

with open("/home/ninky/com.csv", "r") as fp:
    content = fp.read()
lines = content.split("\n")
print(lines)


myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", database="EMPSALARY")
cur = myconn.cursor()

db = "insert into PERSON (name,age,year) values (%s,%s,%s)"
for l in lines:
    data=l.split(',')
    cur.execute(db, data)
myconn.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ninky/PycharmProjects/new/csv_db.py", line 18, in <module>
    myconn = cur.execute(db, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 518, in execute
    if not self._connection:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists       Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, i edited the question. You have to remove the myconn= before the cur.execute. try now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ninky/PycharmProjects/new/csv_db.py", line 18, in <module>
    cur.execute(db, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 540, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 78, in __call__
    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: commit was missing, so it was not reflecting in the db. my bad.